# A quantity measuring the reflexivity of Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Recall that $(y_{n})_{n}$ is a convex block subsequence of a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in a Banach space $X$ provided that there exists a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $(k_{n})_{n}$ so that $y_{n}\in \textrm{co}(x_{i})_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}$ for every $n$ ($k_{0}=0$).
The collection of all convex block subsequences of $(x_{n})_{n}$ will be denoted by $\textrm{cbs}((x_{n})_{n})$.

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a bounded sequence in a Banach space $X$. We set $$\textrm{ca}((x_{n})_{n})=\inf_{n}\sup_{k,l\geq n}\|x_{k}-x_{l}\|.$$
Then $(x_{n})_{n}$ is norm-Cauchy if and only if $\textrm{ca}((x_{n})_{n})=0$.

Let $X$ be a Banach space. We set $$R(X)=\sup_{(x_{n})_{n}\subseteq B_{X}}\inf_{(z_{n})_{n}\in \textrm{cbs}((x_{n})_{n})}\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n}).$$

We have proved that a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if and only if $R(X)=0$.

Furthermore, we have shown that $R(X)=2$ if $X$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $l_{1}$ (not contains $l_{1}$ as a subset), and $R(c)=2$, where $c$ denotes the space of all convergent scalar sequences equipped with the supremum norm. My concern is $R(c_{0})$.

Question. Is $R(c_{0})\leq 1$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks interesting but is difficult to read. Is it possible to introduce $Y := X^{\mathbb{N}}$ and replace $(x_n)_n$ by $x$? And what is $B_X$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka $B_{X}$ denotes the closed unit ball of $X$.

Comment: If I understand your claim correctly that: if $X$ contains $\ell_1$, then $R(X)=2$. Thus $R(c_0)=2$, because $\ell_1\subset c_0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please note: "contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell_1$'' is not the same as  "contains  $\ell_1$ as a subset''.

Comment: @JohannLangemets  $X$ contains an isomorphic copy of $l_{1}$ means that $X$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $l_{1}$, not just contains $l_{1}$ as a subset,

Comment: @DirkWerner  Thank you for your suggestion. I add the note.

Comment: How do you see that $R(c)=2$?

Comment: @BillJohnson  I give the answer below.

Comment: @DongyangChen Yes, of course, I read it too quickly and thought of a subset. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof that $R(c_0)\le 4/3$.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in the unit ball of $c_0$. By passing to a subsequence we can assume that $x_n$ converges coordinate wise to a vector $x$ in the unit ball of $\ell_\infty$. By passing to another subsequence and making a small perturbation we can assume that there are $k_1<k_2<\dots$ so that $x_n$ is supported on $1,\dots,k_n$ and $1_{[1,k_n]} x_{n+1} = 1_{[1,k_n]} x$. Let $z_n:= (2/3)x_{2n} + (1/3)x_{2n+1}$.  A simple computation shows that if $z$ is in the convex hull of
$\{z_k : k>n \}$, then $\|z_n-z\|\le 4/3$. Thus $ca((z_n))_n \le 4/3$.

EDIT 27.12.2020: On any interval $(k_{n-1}, k_n]$, if $k\not= n$, then $1_{(k_{n-1}, k_n]}x_k $ is either $0$ or $1_{(k_{n-1},k_n]}x$. Consequently, if $z$ and $w$ are both averages of $N$ different $x_n$'s, then $\|z-w\| \le 1 + 1/N$. From this it follows that $R(c_0)\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. We can prove that $R(X)\geq 1$ if $X$ is non-reflexive. Therefore $R(c_{0})\geq 1$. I hope to prove that $R(c_{0})\leq 1$ and then $R(c_{0})=1$. This is optimal. I do not know if your proof yields $R(c_{0})\leq 1$.

Comment: @DongyangChen Just take $z_n:=\frac{p-1}{p}x_{2n}+\frac{1}{p}x_{2n+1}$.

Comment: @BenW  What's the $p$? You means the $p$ is bigger than 1 ?

Comment: $p$ is meant to be an arbitrary integer $>1$, yes.  Then $\|z_n-z\|\leq 1+\frac{1}{p}$ which yields $R(c_0)=1$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, Bill and Ben.

Comment: I don't think that it right, Ben. Look at the piece of $z_n - z_{n+1}$ between $k_{2n-1}$ and $k_{2n}$. As far as I can tell, $z_n - z_{n+1}$ might have norm $(2p-2)/p$ on that piece.  I think that $4/3$ is the best one can do with convex combinations of only $2$ of the $x_k$. Using $p=2$ reduces the norm of $z_n - z_{n+1}$ on that piece to one, but on the next piece, between $k_{2n}$ and $k_{2n+1}$, the norm of $z_n - z_{n+1}$ might go up to $3/2$.

Comment: @BillJohnson As far as you tell, a simple computation shows that if $z$ is in the convex hull of $\{z_{k}:k>2n+1\}$, then $\|z_{n}-z\|\leq \frac{4}{3}$. Thus $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n})\leq \frac{4}{3}$. How do you see that $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n})\leq \frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: I do not understand your question, @DongyangChen. The "simple computation" works for every $n$, from which the "Thus" statement is obvious.

Comment: @BillJohnson  It seems that the ''Thus'' statement is not obvious. Maybe I miss something?  Your simple computation actually shows that $\|z_{n}-z_{m}\|\leq \frac{4}{3}$ for every $n$ and every $m>2n+1$. It seems that this does not imply that $\|z_{k}-z_{l}\|\leq \frac{4}{3}$ for all $k,l\geq N$ for some $N$.

Comment: @BillJohnson  I make a computation  and show that $\|z_{n}-z_{m}\|\leq \frac{4}{3}$ for every $n$ and every $m>n$, not $m>2n+1$.

Comment: Oh, the problem was a typo that I made. I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$, we define $x_{n}(i)=1, i\leq n$ and $x_{n}(i)=-1,i>n$. Given any $(z_{n})_{n}\in \textrm{cbs}((x_{n})_{n})$, $z_{n}=\sum\limits_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}\lambda_{i}x_{i}$. Then, for $n<m$, we get
$$\sum\limits_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_{n}}\lambda_{i}x_{i}(k_{m-1}+1)=-1, \quad \sum\limits_{i=k_{m-1}+1}^{k_{m}}\lambda_{i}x_{i}(k_{m-1}+1)=1.$$
This implies that $\|z_{n}-z_{m}\|=2$ and so $\textrm{ca}((z_{n})_{n})=2$. Thus, we obtain $R(c)=2$.